# nullptr not declared in scopt WITH c++11 support

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, nullptr

I have installed:
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

As IDE I use either eclipse CDT or Code::Blocks, does not matter which one. I will stick to Code::Blocks for now. If i use a null pointer in my code I get:
    nullptr was not declared in this scope

All research related cross postings just say, if compiler supports C++11 (Version 4.8.2 should do), add

```
-std=c++11
```

as parameter. I have done it in both IDE  does not turn of the error message. In CodeBlocks this is done by
settings -> compiler (Gnu GCC Compiler is selected) and checking:
    Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard

Still I got the error message.

Comment: Your compiler version looks ok. Try to compile the file from command prompt with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: This works reliably with GCC 4.8.2 and Code::Blocks (I'm using it).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with gcc 4.8.2 when using nullptr and compiling with -std=c++11 flag.

It turns out I had -ansi flag appearing after -std=c++11 which made gcc using ansi compiler option and silently ignoring -std=c++11. Removing the ansi flag or any other conflicting -std flags, like -std=c90 or -std=iso9899:1990, would do the trick.